# inresar valores en el input

Tags: javascript, html

Hola tengo este elemento en mi dom

```
<input type="text" name="first_name_more_info" id="first_name_more_info" placeholder="Nombres *" autocomplete="off">
```

Con js estoy intentando ingresar un valor pero no lo toma

```
document.getElementsByClassName('first_name_more_info').value = 'jhon'
```

Cuando se ejecuta el input sigue sin ningun dato

Comment: cambia `getElementsByClassName` por `getElementById`

Comment: con `getElementById` lo tienes, saludos

Comment: Gracias, me soluciono el problema

Comment: Gracias, me soluciono el problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso deberías usar el `getElementById` para acceder al id ya que no tienes ninguna clase definida en el input por lo tanto el método que estás usando del DOM: `getElementsByClassName` es erróneo.

Tu código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
document.getElementById('first_name_more_info').value = 'jhon';
```